# sequelize - pass query over http (serialize/stringify)

Tags: sequelize.js

I want pass queries from one server to another one over http.
So for example, the following query, I need to serialise and de-serialize.

```
const query = { where: {value: { [Op.like]: `%${search}%` } }};
```

the our put of `JSON.stringify(query)` will be:
`{"where":{"value":{}}}`

Which is not correct, how is that possible?

Thanks

Comment: You can't stringify it because of `[Op.like]`. You could just generate SQL and send that, but this is likely to be insecure so should not be publically available. Or just send the argument and reconstruct the query on the query server.

Comment: Try to use string based operators as keys on first server and send valid stringified object to the server which should execute sql and there use `reduce` method on query object keys to replace string based operators with sequelize's valid symbol based ones. Don't use string based operators directly in sequelize query as they are deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Javascript's symbol type is not serializable by default ([Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)). There are a number of reasons that this is a less optimal approach though:

- It's not the best pattern to construct queries outside of the service that is running them - not only do you run into this problem (specifically with Sequelize), but you also open yourself up to attack vectors if you let your service run code from an outside source.
- You're tying your caller to the specific logic and format of your service, so you're going to have a harder time refactoring your code if you need to.
- You're increasing the payload size unnecessarily. In your case this may not be an issue but if you're coding for high throughput this can really drain your resources with no tangible benefit.

The better approach is to pass the parts of your query that you know will change in a serialized message and then construct the query on the receiving end; that way you can utilize the symbols since you'll have no need to serialize them, you reduce the attack space for bad actors, you reduce network load, and you encapsulate more of your internal workings so that if you need to make adjustments, the caller doesn't always have to be aware of them. In this instance, you'd just pass

```
{
    "search": <search_term>
}
```

And then in your service you'd construct the query:

```
const query = { where: {value: { [Op.like]: `%${parameters.search}%` } }};
```